# How to use a generic approach to define React components by reusing code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, single-page-application

I currently have a couple of React components that looks similar in terms of functionality. They all have similar methods used to fetch data a server and update each component's state by making an API to different endpoints.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import AppService from '../lib/service';

class Factorial extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: '',
        }
    }

    getNext() {
        AppService.getNextFactorial().then(data => {
            this.setState({ value: data.data.gen })
        })
    }

    resetFactorial() {
        AppService.resetNextFactorial().then(data => {
            this.setState({ value: data.data.reset })
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={'functionsWrapper'}>
                <h2> Factorial Sequence Generator </h2>
                <p> Click to get the next value in the sequence </p>
                <button onClick={() => this.getNext()}> Get Next</button>
                <button onClick={() => this.resetFactorial()}> Reset </button>

                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="body" defaultValue={this.state.value} name="body" className="form-input" />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(Factorial);
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AppService from '../lib/service';

class Fibonacci extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: '',
        }
    }

    getNext() {
        AppService.getNextFibonacci().then(data => {
            this.setState({ value: data.data.gen })
        })
    }

    resetFibonacci() {
        AppService.resetNextFibonacci().then(data => {
            this.setState({ value: data.data.reset })
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={'functionsWrapper'}>
                <h2> Fibonacci Sequence Generator </h2>
                <p> Click to get the next value in the sequence </p>
                <button onClick={() => this.getNext()}> Get Next</button>
                <button onClick={() => this.resetFibonacci()}> Reset </button>

                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="body" defaultValue={this.state.value} name="body" className="form-input" />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Fibonacci;
```

What I want to achieve is to be able split the functions of each component and make it reusable so that I can have a generic approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function that generates components(which has in it the core functionality), and pass the differences as parameters.

```
    // componentGenerator.js
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import AppService from '../lib/service';

    const componentGenerator = (getNextThing, resetThing, title) => (
    class extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                value: '',
            }
        }

        getNext() {
            AppService[getNextThing]().then(data => {
                this.setState({ value: data.data.gen })
            })
        }

        reset() {
            AppService[resetThing]().then(data => {
                this.setState({ value: data.data.reset })
            })
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div className={'functionsWrapper'}>
                    <h2> {title} </h2>
                    <p> Click to get the next value in the sequence </p>
                    <button onClick={() => this.getNext()}> Get Next</button>
                    <button onClick={() => this.reset()}> Reset </button>

                    <div>
                        <input type="text" id="body" defaultValue={this.state.value} name="body" className="form-input" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    })

    export default componentGenerator;


    // Factorial.js
    import componentGenerator from './componentGenerator';

    export default withRouter(componentGenerator('getNextFactorial', 'resetNextFactorial', 'Factorial Sequence Generator'));


    // Fibonacci.js
    import componentGenerator from './componentGenerator';

    export default withRouter(componentGenerator('getNextFibonacci', 'resetNextFibonacci', 'Fibonacci Sequence Generator'));
```

Answer (score 2):

**helper.js**

```
import AppService from '../lib/service';

export function resetFibonacci() {
    AppService.resetNextFibonacci().then(data => {
        this.setState({ value: data.data.reset })
    });    
}
```

> NOTE: use function insted of an arrow function "() => {}"

**Fibonacci.js** (your component)

```
import * as Helpers from './helpers.js';
...
resetFibonacci() {
  Helpers.resetFibonacci.call(this);
}
```

> NOTE: bind **this** to the function scope.

Comment: I really want to avoid declaring state in all the components, I was hoping for an approach where I can reduce duplication of code. btw, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Right! so to avoid duplicating code you can create a single component to handle this. I'll right a new answer soon :) Happy to help.

Comment: Using `bind` here just returns a new function, it's not calling it. Using `call` or `apply` would make more sense.